# ggarrange: combine multiple plots

Tags: r

[image]

The attached picture is from the following article and is using ggarrange to merge those plots:
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/

```
ggarrange(sp,                                                 # First row with scatter plot
          ggarrange(bxp, dp, ncol = 2, labels = c("B", "C")), # Second row with box and dot plots
          nrow = 2, 
          labels = "A"                                        # Labels of the scatter plot
          )
```

I would like to create the same plot, but instead of having two smaller plots in the bottom and a larger one on the top, I would like to inverse it: Two small plots (A and B) on the top and a larger plot C in the bottom

I tried using the following code with no success:

```
ggarrange(
  plot1, plot2,           
  ggarrange(plot3, nrow = 2, labels = c("C")), 
  ncol = 2, 
  labels = c("A","B")       
)
```

With this code I just see plot3 in the top left corner.

Comment: Try `ggarrange(ggarrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=2), plot3, nrow=2)` with labels.

Answer (score 6):

The [patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/patchwork.html) package makes this stuff a bit easier

```
library(patchwork)
(plot1 | plot2) / plot3 + plot_annotation(tag_levels ="A")
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to put the 3rd label correctly, we need another call to `ggarrange` inside the 1st call.

```
ggarrange(ggarrange(bxp, dp, ncol = 2, labels = c("A", "B")), 
          ggarrange(sp, labels = "C"), 
          nrow = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to arrange the plots in the correct order, and then add a blank to the first element of the second labels.

```
library(ggplot2); library(ggpubr)

bxp <- ggboxplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len")
dp <- ggdotplot(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len")
scp <- ggscatter(ToothGrowth, x = "dose", y = "len")

ggarrange(ggarrange(bxp, dp, ncol = 2, labels = c("A", "B")), scp, 
          labels = c("","C"), nrow = 2)
```

[image]