# Modify display order of ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am displaying several `ggplots` into a `ggarrange` matrix.
`ggarrange` displays each subsequent plot one by one by column and starts with a new row when the last column is reached.

What I would like to do is to display each plot by row then start with a new column when the last row is reached.

Here is an example

```
##### Import libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

##### Initiating objects
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), 25, 4))
listggplots <- list()
k <- 0
vecColors <- rep(c("#21b78c", "#21a0b7", "#2143b7", "#b521b7"), each=4)

##### Filling list of ggplots
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(df)){
    k <- k + 1
    dfTemp <- df[, c(i, j)]
    colnames(dfTemp) <- c("var1", "var2")
    listggplots[[k]] <- ggplot(dfTemp, aes(var1, var2)) + 
      geom_point(size=10, color=vecColors[k]) + 
      scale_x_continuous(name=colnames(df)[i]) + 
      scale_y_continuous(name=colnames(df)[j]) + 
      theme(legend.position="none", axis.title=element_text(size=12))
  }
}

##### Display plots
ggarrange(plotlist=c(listggplots), nrow=4, ncol=4)
```

[image]

As we can see, the current matrix order for displaying plots is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
[3,]    9   10   11   12
[4,]   13   14   15   16
```

I would like each column to have only one ggplot color.
So the order of the matrix would be:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    5    9   13
[2,]    2    6   10   14
[3,]    3    7   11   15
[4,]    4    8   12   16
```

I found the following topic but it is manual disposition of plots and I would like something automatic.
[ggarrange: combine multiple plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62750077/ggarrange-combine-multiple-plots)

Thank you for any idea

Comment: To clarify, you don't only want the column to be same color, but also the same variables? In other words you would want column one to be all green and have X2 on the y axis and X1 on the x axis?

Comment: @HanselPalencia the axis order is correct, it is just the plot order that I would like to modify. I coloured the plots just to have the idea of the order of plots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual, *ggarrange* is just a wrapper.

> ggarrange {ggpubr}
> ...
> Arrange multiple ggplots on the same page. Wrapper around plot_grid(). ...

The original *plot_grid* has *byrow* argument:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = listggplots, byrow = FALSE, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward by switching the color mapping in your `rep()` function and switching the naming conventions of the `i` and `j` in the `scale_x/y_continuous()`

See below

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

##### Initiating objects
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), 25, 4))
listggplots <- list()
k <- 0
vecColors <- rep(c("#21b78c", "#21a0b7", "#2143b7", "#b521b7"), 4)

##### Filling list of ggplots
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(df)){
    k <- k + 1
    dfTemp <- df[, c(j, i)]
    colnames(dfTemp) <- c("var1", "var2")
    listggplots[[k]] <- ggplot(dfTemp, aes(var1, var2)) + 
      geom_point(size=10, color=vecColors[k]) + 
      scale_x_continuous(name=colnames(df)[j]) + 
      scale_y_continuous(name=colnames(df)[i]) + 
      theme(legend.position="none", axis.title=element_text(size=12))
  }
}

##### Display plots
ggarrange(plotlist=c(listggplots), nrow=4, ncol=4)
```

[image]

Update Based on Comment ------

If you want to keep the axis order as above, then don't change the `i` and `j` positions.

```
##### Import libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

##### Initiating objects
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), 25, 4))
listggplots <- list()
k <- 0
vecColors <- rep(c("#21b78c", "#21a0b7", "#2143b7", "#b521b7"), 4)

##### Filling list of ggplots
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(df)){
    k <- k + 1
    dfTemp <- df[, c(i, j)]
    colnames(dfTemp) <- c("var1", "var2")
    listggplots[[k]] <- ggplot(dfTemp, aes(var1, var2)) + 
      geom_point(size=10, color=vecColors[k]) + 
      scale_x_continuous(name=colnames(df)[i]) + 
      scale_y_continuous(name=colnames(df)[j]) + 
      theme(legend.position="none", axis.title=element_text(size=12))
  }
}

##### Display plots
ggarrange(plotlist=c(listggplots), nrow=4, ncol=4)
```

[image]

Comment: zx8754 answer is perfect. Thank you also for your code proposition

Answer (score 0):

The plots can be ordered easily by

```
n <- ncol(df)
plts <- listggplots[(1:(n^2)) %>% matrix(ncol=n) %>% t %>% as.vector]
ggarrange(plotlists=plts, nrow=n, ncol=n)
```